# Java display list from 2D array by grouping?

Tags: java

I have a  fairly easy question. I just need the logic or code. I'll be very grateful.

Suppose i have a 2d array like below:

```
[
['Main Menu', 'User Menu', 'Account', 'Enquiries', 'Query by Name'],
['Main Menu', 'User Menu', 'Account', 'Enquiries', 'Query by ID'],
['Main Menu', 'User Menu', 'Account', 'Create', 'Create Type'],
['Main Menu', 'User Menu', 'Account', 'Create', 'Create Account'],
['Main Menu', 'User Menu', 'Client', 'Enquiries', 'Query by Client Name'],
['Main Menu', 'User Menu', 'Client', 'Create', 'Create Client']
]
```

I want the program to display like this

```
Main Menu
-User Menu
--Account
---Enquiries
----Query by Name
----Query by ID

Main Menu
-User Menu
--Account
---Create
----Create Type
----Create Account

Main Menu
-User Menu
--Client
---Enquiries
----Query by Client Name

Main Menu
-User Menu
--Client
---Create
----Create Client
```

By the way, if there is another way to store data other than using 2D arrays which would make the above display easier to code, you can mention it.

Comment: Create a class `Menu` with a variable `Menu parentMenu`. With this you could easily create a representive tree of a menu. That would be a more OOP oriented approach to the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class `Menu` like shown below:

```
class Menu{
  private String name;           // menu name
  private List<Menu> subMenu;    // list of sub menus
  // getter and setter

  // recursive method for displaying menus in desired format
  public String displayString(String prefix) {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      if(subMenu != null){
          for (Menu menu : subMenu) {
              builder.append(menu.displayString(prefix + " "));
          }
      }

      return prefix + name + "\n" + builder.toString();
   }
}
```

Using this structure you can easily store your data and print it the way you want.

Comment: Might be better to use a `Map` instead of `List`!

Comment: Yes but if i have thousands of varying records, the setter for each would be different. A logic involving some sort of sorting would be best to achieve the required display. I am sorry if i am wrong. I am quite new to programming.

Comment: What do you mean that "setter for each would be different"? Do you want to sort menus at same level, on the basis of `name` attribute?

Comment: @flkes What would be key of the map and what would be its purpose?

Comment: Key would be the `Menu#name` for that entry. It gives a more useful interface for navigating a text based menu. Lookup's by string, being able to return key set or value set with a simple getter, etc

Comment: @user2228135 I added one new recursive method `displayString()` to get display string. You can change it according to your need.

Comment: @flkes I see your point, yes key can be menu id which can be used on UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the jagged array design in your question, which I personally don't have a problem with (many ways to skin all cats), simply use an inner for-loop approach:

```
for (String[] menuList : menuArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < menuList.length; i++) {
        //print out values
    }
}
```

Also, while you may have simply written the code for brevity, bear in mind your 2D array syntax wouldn't compile.